# How do I search for names starting wih A in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I have a question that how can we use SELECT for searching the name which start with 'A' in MySQL table?
thanks

Comment: W3Schools is brilliant for learning SQL.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE columnname LIKE 'A%'
```

Answer (score 6):

[MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

```
... LIKE 'A%'
```

(the first part of the query should be easy for you)

Comment: why the downvote? Because I didn't write the obvious parts for educational purposes?

Comment: i want to get all names starts with A or B or C till I so i used `LIKE '[ABCDEFGHI]%'` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

Using the [`LIKE` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like), e.g.:

```
SELECT lastName FROM yourTable WHERE lastName LIKE 'A%'
```

Comment: i want to get all names starts with A or B or C till I so i used `LIKE '[ABCDEFGHI]%'` but it doesn't work

Comment: @MahmoudS: Why would you think it would? There's nothing in the docs suggesting that it supports regex-style character classes. You need to use a bunch of `OR LIKE` (or, as this is MySQL, use [`SUBSTRING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) combined with [`INSTR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) or [`LOCATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate)).

Comment: i was able to accomplish it as follows `where name REGEXP '^[A-I]' `

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name FROM <tablename> WHERE name like "A%"
```

Answer (score 2):

You use the `LIKE` command. The `%` is a wildcard.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column like 'A%';
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_wildcards.asp

```
SELECT * FROM Persons
WHERE Name LIKE 'A%'
```