# Select from MySQL from a given string to the next given string

Tags: mysql, sql

[Image with part of the database in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijJfJ.png)

I have this table

```
id ¦ Follow 
1 ¦ Route 1
2 ¦ Store 1
3 ¦ Store 2
4 ¦ end
5 ¦ Route 2
6 ¦ Store 3
7 ¦ Store 4
8 ¦ end
etc, etc
```

So, what I try to understand is how can I get only the rows starting from Route Number (i.e Route 2) until the first "end" is found? Routes are subject to change so it have to be from string "Route number" to the next "end" met.

The solution may be very simple but I have no clue where to start from, as I am quite new in this area and I haven't found anything relevant on SO. Please let me know if you want me to be more specific.

Thanks!

Comment: Using Like queries is a good Option. Here is an example as a start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100360/how-do-i-search-for-names-starting-wih-a-in-mysql
Found another one  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019482/mysql-select-until-in-sql

Comment: You cann't do this with simple query. Try to use stored procedure or just do this from your client code.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no concept of next unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: I've added a screen shot with the database in phpmyadmin. Maybe will bring more light.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c6f1/1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me assume that you have a column that specifies the ordering, uniquely.  I'll call it `id`.  Then you can do:

```
select t.*
from t cross join
     (select id
      from t
      where name = 'Route 2'
     ) tt
where t.id >= tt.id and
      t.id <= (select min(t2.id)
               from t t2
               where t2.id > t.id and
                     t2.name = 'end'
              );
```

I should note that you have a very arcane data structure.  I think you might reconsider how the data is stored.

Comment: @ceucaciprian This actually works if `where t2.id > t.id` is changed to `where t2.id > tt.id` - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c6f1/4

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much, Druv Saxena! And thank you again, Gordon!